# Creating a toggle button that hides and unhides rows based on a value of "0" in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've been trying to research specific VBA code that will allow me to create a toggle button and have had no real luck.

In column "I" of my worksheet, I've specified values that use "0" and want a code that hides and unhides rows that match with the "0" value in column "I".

I have also been trying to create a toggle button that when selected would hide and unhide my rows. It starts from row 7 and ends on row 491.

This is the code I've been working with, but have not had any luck with running it correctly. Would be much appreciated if anyone could help!

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
Dim xAddress As String
xAddress = "I"
If ToggleButton1.Value Then
    Application.ActiveSheet.Rows(xAddress).Hidden = True
Else
    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub PG1(ByVal Target As Range)
    If .Range("E7").Value = "Passed" Then
        Rows("7:491").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    ElseIf Range("E7").Value = "Failed" Then
        Rows("7:491").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

On my test sheet I created 2 toggle buttons:

- `ToggleButton1` (hides and unhides 0's in column I)
- `ToggleButton2` (hides and unhides rows 7:491)

Here is the code for both:

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    With Me
        If .ToggleButton1.Value = False Then
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .UsedRange.AutoFilter
            .ToggleButton1.Caption = "Hide 0's"
        Else
            .UsedRange.Columns(9).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0"
            .ToggleButton1.Caption = "Show 0's"
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub ToggleButton2_Click()
    Dim e7 As String, changed As Boolean

    With Me
        e7 = .Range("E7").Value2
        If .ToggleButton2.Value = False Then
            .Rows("7:491").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            .ToggleButton2.Caption = "Hide Rows"
        Else
            changed = (e7 = "Passed" Or e7 = "Failed")
            .Rows("7:491").EntireRow.Hidden = changed
            If changed Then .ToggleButton2.Caption = "Show All Rows"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

When hiding and unhiding rows with buttons on them, the buttons might get moved or hidden so

In Design Mode:

- Right-click each button
- Select `Format Control`
- Go to the 3rd tab (Properties)
- Select "Don't move or size with cells"